# Linux grep for file starting with certain letter AND contain certain words

Tags: linux, grep, find, filenames

Trying to search a file directory for file names beginning with "h" and containing "enu"?

So far this is what I've got, I just don't know how to handle both grep statements in one command line?

```
find fs282/path/web/en_US.dic -exec grep "^h" {} \;
```

Comment: @ilkkachu sorry for confusion. Files with names starting with h and containing enu

Comment: What does the `fs282/path/web/en_US.dic` file (?) have to do with this, or is it a directory?

Comment: @ElonCode, yep, it's the use of `grep` that I found confusing, as `grep` is mainly used to look at the contents of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To look at the file names, use the `-name` condition of `find`. It should take regular filename patterns, so `h*enu*` matches what you want.

```
find /some/path -name "h*enu*"
```

`grep` would instead look at the contents of the files, line by line, so this would look for lines matching the pattern:

```
find /some/path -type f -exec grep '^h.*enu' /dev/null {} +
```

(The output would be the lines, not just the file names.)

`grep` expects a regular expression as opposed to glob wildcards for `-name`. Also, `grep` looks for matches *within* the lines as opposed to full matches with `-name`, hence the `^` to anchor the pattern at the start of the line. The `/dev/null` is only  there  to  make sure the file names are always printed for each matching line, even when there's only one  matching file. With the GNU implementation of `grep`, one may use the `-H` option instead.

Comment: (argh, brainfarted with that grep, thanks Stéphane.)